# MySQL Specific Group by

Tags: mysql

Let's think we have the following table:

```
id  |  name  |  time
 1  |  Test  |  10
 2  |  Test  |  24
 3  |  Test  |  30
 4  |  ABCD  |  10
 5  |  ABCD  |  89
 6  |  EFGH  |  5
 7  |  WXYZ  |  5
 8  |  WXYZ  |  7
 9  |  Test  |  10
10  |  Test  |  24
11  |  EFGH  |  7
```

I want to get the following output with a query:

```
name  |  min_time  |  max_time
Test  |        10  |        30
ABCD  |        10  |        89
EFGH  |         5  |         5
WXYZ  |         5  |         7
Test  |        10  |        24
EFGH  |         7  |         7
```

Something like GROUP BY but with a history...

```
SELECT name, MIN(time), MAX(time)
FROM table
GROUP BY name
ODER BY id ASC
```

With this query it would only group EVERY name together... But I want it only grouped when the same name is after or before the row.

Does someone know how to do this exactly?

Comment: Check this article out. http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
select name, min(time), max(time)
from (
select
name, 
time,
@group_num := if(@name != name, @group_num + 1, @group_num) AS group_number,
@name := name
from yourTable
, (select @group_num := 1, @name := NULL) variables
order by id
) sq
group by group_number
```

Comment: It'll work if you change `@row_num` to `@group_num` in the 6th line. [SQL fiddle for reference...](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83926/4/0)

Comment: Ah, yes, thanks Marty. Copy&pasted parts of the query, was in a hurry. @jannicars Please try again, corrected the query.