# sql get the member with the most consecutive value of 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the sql to return the memberid 2 because I want to get the member with the most **consecutive** value of 1 even if memberid 1 as four times the value 1.

```
memberid position createdat
======== ======== =========
1        1         9/1/2001
1        1         8/1/2001
2        1         7/1/2001
2        1         6/1/2001
2        1         5/1/2001
1        1         4/1/2001
1        1         3/1/2001
```

Thanks a million times for any help.

Comment: Do you have an ordering column somewhere else? You'll need that to establish the meaning of "consecutive" in context of the query.

Comment: I've added a createdat ... Thanks

Comment: Check out this question: [MySQL Specific Group by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18796096/mysql-specific-group-by/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use parameters as counters. In the below @r is incremented for each row as long as the member is the same as the previous row (as defined by the order by), if it is not the same member @r resets to 1:

```
SELECT  MemberID
FROM    (   SELECT  MemberID,
                    Position,
                    CreateDat,
                    @r:=IF(@m = MemberID, @r + 1, 1) AS Consec,
                    @m:= MemberID
            FROM    T,
                    (SELECT @r:= 0) r,
                    (SELECT @m:= 0) m
            ORDER BY CreateDat DESC
        ) t
ORDER BY Consec DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25ed9/3)**

**EDIT**

With a slight tweek you can get a bit more information out to, such as when the consecutive period started and ended:

```
SELECT  MemberID, FirstCreateDat, CreateDat, Consec
FROM    (   SELECT  MemberID,
                    Position,
                    CreateDat,
                    @r:=IF(@m = MemberID, @r + 1, 1) AS Consec,
                    @d:=IF(@m = MemberID, @d, CreateDat) AS FirstCreateDat,
                    @m:= MemberID
            FROM    T,
                    (SELECT @r:= 0) r,
                    (SELECT @m:= 0) m,
                    (SELECT @d:= CAST(NULL AS DATETIME)) d
            ORDER BY CreateDat DESC
        ) t
ORDER BY Consec DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25ed9/2)**